# How to calculate value of the equation

Tags: maxima

I don't know how to calculate my function.

[image: Photo]

I am trying to assign my output expression to a function, but I can't calculate it in my function with parameters. It always returns an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ":=" operator quotes (does not evaluate) its arguments. Note that as you defined it, the body of the function is `%o6` instead of its value.

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want. Try this: use the quote-quote `''` operator to paste the expression into the function definition like this.

```
ge(r, t) := ''%o6;
```